# How to sniff non-http traffic (sockets) on Genymotion/Android Emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, genymotion, socks, packet-sniffers

I'm trying to reverse engineer one Android app's traffic and it's using sockets, xmpp or something else, but not http(s) on some features. I know this because Charles does not see some requests, but data is definitely coming from the server for sure (e.g. chat messages).

Android allows to set http(s) proxy, not socks. ProxyDroid doesn't work on genymotion, because it's x86 and ProxyDroid doesn't support that. Tried Drony app on genymotion, which supposedly should allow socks proxy, but once I try turning it on, the whole emulator restarts (probably crashes).

So how do I sniff/trace/inspect sockets traffic on Genymotion/Android emulator?

Comment: Did you try Fiddler?

Comment: Charles or Fiddler isn't the issue, I can't find a way to set SOCKS proxy for android emulator in the first place. And those two are for http(s) sniffing anyway

Answer (score 3):

You might have better luck by doing it on the host side, ie from the Windows/Mac/Linux machine running Genymotion.

### The basics

1. Install [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org)
2. Start Wireshark and select the network interface which connects you to the Internet (or to the server you are interested in). For me it is `wlp1s0`.

[image: Selecting the capture interface in Wireshark]

3. Tell Wireshark you only want traffic going from your device to the server you are interested by entering `ip.dst == <server-ip>` in the filter line. Now go back to your device and use the application which communicates with the server. Traffic should appear in Wireshark. Here I am browsing my web site, whose IP address is 5.135.144.176:

[image: Watching traffic with Wireshark]

Note that if Wireshark knows about the protocol used by the server, you can filter it. Here is the same output with the http filter:

[image: Watching HTTP traffic with Wireshark]

### Watching only traffic from the device

With the current setup, if you access the server from your host, this traffic will be logged by Wireshark as well. To avoid that you need to do the following:

1. Configure your device in Bridge mode: stop the device, open its settings dialog and select Bridge:

[image: Configuring Genymotion in Bridge mode]

2. Get the device IP address: restart the device, open the "Settings" application and go to "About phone > Status", note the IP address:

[image: The Android Status screen]

3. Add this IP address to the filter line in wireshark, like so: `ip.src == <the-device-ip> and ip.dst == <the-server-ip>`.

Comment: if you truly want to help people, could you provide more details?

Comment: how about that @Gintas_ ?

Comment: the traffic is encrypted when it reaches wireshark your solution is not helpful at all