# How to capture the traffic of Genymotion Emulator with tcpdump?

Tags: genymotion, tcpdump

I have an android device (simulated with Genymotion on top off virtualBox) on my host computer(ubuntu).

which interface I should capture to have both incoming and outgoing traffic of android devices?

Answer (score 3):

Download tcpdump for android from here: https://www.androidtcpdump.com/android-tcpdump/downloads

Use the following commands to setup all the things.

```
adb root 
adb remount 
adb push ./tcpdump /system/xbin/tcpdump
```

## ToUse:

```
adb shell
tcpdump -D
tcpdump -vv -i any -s 0 -w /sdcard/dump.pcap
adb pull /sdcard/dump.pcap .
```

Then analyze the pcap file in Wireshark if you want.

Answer (score 0):

This answer might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/48062718/20107. It's using Wireshark but it should be easy to adapt to tcpdump.